# Any good Mac|Linux software that will assist in writing version log files?

Tags: version-control, versioning

Pretty much the question I wrote in the title.

Im just getting tired of filling in the version log text files manually all the time.

Comment: I think you may need to specify an SCM first, the question seems to vague to answer well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends of what level of changes you are going to describe. If it is source-based then something like timeline from [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) will be helpful. But I prefer to do less detailed version log file mainly with logic changes.